# How do I understand why my Flink TaskManager quits shortly after starting my job?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm using Flink 1.15 Docker images in Session mode pretty much the same as the [Compose documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/deployment/resource-providers/standalone/docker/#session-mode-1). I have one Task Manager. A few minutes after starting my streaming job I get a stack dump log message from my Job Manager stating that the Task Manager is no longer reachable and I see that my Task Manager Docker container has exited with code 137 - which possibly indicates an out of memory error. Although `docker inspect` shows the `OOMKilled` flag as `false` indicating some sort of other issue.

End of stack trace from Job Manager log:

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMasterException: TaskManager with id 172.18.0.5:44333-7c7193 is no longer reachable.
```

The TaskManager Docker logs produce no error whatsoever before exiting. If I resurrect the dead Task Manager Docker container and have a look at the log file in `/opt/flink/logs/` then the last messages state that the various components in my pipeline have switched from INITIALIZING to RUNNING.

I would have expected an out of memory stack dump from the task manager if my state had become too large. Also `docker inspect` shows that the container did not exit because of an out of memory error.

I have no idea what causes my Task Manager to die. Any ideas how I can figure out what is causing the issue? (This happens on 1.15.1 & 1.15.2. I haven't used any other version of Flink.)

Comment: My suspicion would that your Flink job is using too much resources and therefore the TaskManager becomes unavailable. Perhaps you're storing a lot in state or your experiencing a lot of backpressure which causes state to grow too. It probably would be good to setup some metrics to see if that returns anything suspicious.

Comment: I suspect you are right - I just updated the question to show that the exit code of the Docker container is 137. However detecting which part of my job is using too much memory is proving difficult. The Flink web UI only shows it using a small fraction of available heap memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using nothing more sophisticated than trial and error with a variety of different test jobs. I'm not 100% sure I fixed the problem as the issue of the Task Manager crashing without an stack dump occurred sporadically. However the Task Manager hasn't crashed for several days.

The simplest job to recreate my issue was with a `SourceFunction` outputting a continuous stream of incrementing `Long`s straight to a `DiscardingSink`. With this setup the Task Manager would crash after a while on my Linux machine sporadically but never on my Mac.

If I added a `Thread.sleep` to the `SourceFunction`s run loop then the crash would eventually occur but take a bit longer.

I tried `Source` framework instead of `SourceFunction` where a `SingleThreadMultiplexSourceReaderBase` repeatedly calls `fetch` on a `SplitReader` to output the `Long`s. There have been fewer crashes since I did this so it didn't work 100%.

I presume my `SourceFunction` was overfilling some sort of buffer or making a task slot unresponsive as it never relinquished a slot once it started. (Or some other completely different explanation.)

I wish the Task Manager gave some sort of indication why it stopped running.

Comment: I also got same difficulties to find root caused why TaskManager is stopped. No OOM message or something. I wish TaskManager print out error on exit.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happened to me when a task manager runs out of memory and when the GC takes too much time trying to free some memory.

I know you said docker inspect doesn't show that it shuts down because of memory issues, but still try to use more RAM or decrease the memory requirements of your tasks and see if it still crashes.

Comment: I agree. I think it is also possible that the exception is being caught and not re-thrown somewhere within Flink codebase so there is no indication why the Task Manager quits. I managed to recreate the situation sporadically with a simple `SourceFunction` that outputs a random string continuously to a `DiscardingSink`. However it only crashes the Task Manger on one machine inconsistently and not on the other at all. (All using the same Docker Compose configuration.) What more can I do to understand the situation - and prevent it other than blindly increasing memory?

Comment: FYI adding more `taskmanager.memory.process.size` does stop my job from crashing - but I would have expected an OOM exception.

Comment: Hi there, I didn't see your message untill now. I'm glad you found the solution!